# Footer in my sidebar

Tags: wordpress, footer, sidebar

I have read the other answers on SOF, and cannot find out where my error is at. On my homepage and other pages selected to no have a sidebar have the footer credits moving up into the side of my site! :(

*Added 4/11/17:*

Here is the footer.php:

```
   <div class="site-info">
Proudly created by <a href="http://www.twitter.com/officialryguy">Ryan Anderson</a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.officialryguy.com/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a>       
    </div><!-- .site-info -->
```

Here is the index.php that I created recently that might have issues??

```
get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php

                /*
                 * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
<?php if (!is_front_page()) {
get_sidebar();
} ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Post your code!

Comment: Sorry Sumon, added above. Noob move, I know, noob move, I'm sorry! :0)

Answer (score 0):

Found what I needed. Stylesheet needed this added to stop the float:

```
.site-info {
clear: both
}
```